# NoSuchFieldError when extending Interface in generic class

Tags: java, generics, types, interface

I have a bean `ArtistEntityBean` extending `GenericEntityBean`:

```
public class ArtistEntityBean extends GenericEntityBean<Artist> {

    public ArtistEntityBean() {
        item = new Artist();
    }

}
```

-

```
public abstract class GenericEntityBean<T extends IntEntity> implements Serializable {

    protected T item;

    public void init(Integer id){
        item.setId(id);
    }
}
```

-

```
public class Artist extends ArtistBaseEntity implements Comparable<Artist> {

...

}
```

-

```
public abstract class ArtistBaseEntity implements IntEntity {

...

}
```

-

```
public interface IntEntity {

    Integer getId();

    void setId(Integer id);
}
```

-

I'm trying to put as much code as possible in the `GenericEntityBean` class, which is why I thought of using an interface in order to be able to set the `id` of the `item`.

This does not work tough, as I get a `NoSuchFieldError` in the constructor of `ArtistEntityBean` and I don't know why?

Comment: How will GenericEntityBean know about item? Its a parent class

Comment: Have you `item` field in `GenericEntityBean`?

Comment: NoSuchFieldError is an runtime exception, and usually only occurs when you somehow mess up your classpath (e.g. use old version of .class at runtime).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If `item` is `public`, `protected` or default you have to use

```
super.item = new Artist();
```

in the constructor of `ArtistEntityBean`.

If it is `private` you have to provide a setter method in the abstract class.

---

**Edit:** If you did not specify `item` in the abstract class then do the following

```
public abstract class GenericEntityBean<T extends IntEntity> implements Serializable {

    protected T item;

    public void init(Integer id){
        item.setId(id);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! It works when using `super.item = new Artist();`. I thought it wouldn't be needed as `item` is inherited.